# How to get data that sent from post method in webpack and pass it to the game scene in phaser 3?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, phaser-framework

After redirecting from my website to the URL of the game host, I can fetch data that I sent with post method from website in phaser3 Webpack configuration in dev server stuff, but I can not store or send fetched data to the game scene.
for example, I want to store username and score to the leaderboard but I cannot do it because I couldn't send the user's username to the game scene.
I will be thankful if anybody helps.

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? What does your code look like? Please consider expanding your question with [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @brae after logging in in the website, I send user's username with post method to the game's URL, I fetch it in base.js file( where the webpack config exists ) in dev server successfully but when I want to redirect from there to index.js ( for running game ) I can not get the username.

Comment: From your description looks like you are implementing some client-server game. But I think you are missing some base concept of that. Please, improve your question with example code so we can understand better where you are stuck.